# No joomla update notification

Tags: joomla-3.x, joomla-3.3.x, update

I want to update my joomla and usually there is an update notification when there is a newer version available.

I'm on 3.0.3 now so it's pretty old, but still no update message to be found anywhere.

[image]

[image]

What can I do about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

go to the extensions -> plugins and then find "Quick Icon - Joomla! Update Notification" and enable it.

Comment: Where can I do that?

Comment: the answer has been edited.

Comment: Thanks that worked! I don't know why someone downvoted the answer.